# Spring Cloud Stream - Kafka binder

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

What is the difference between these 2 binders? Their behaviors are more or less same - like producing, processing and consuming.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_reference_guide

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is specifically for Kafka Streams (`KStream`, `KTable`), the second uses the kafka Consumer and Producer clients directly (via spring-kafka and spring-integration-kafka).